# CakePHP actsAs Translate and $Model::find()

Tags: cakephp, translate

I have attached the Translate behavior to one of my models and I have some shortcomings regarding this:

1) If I don't save data in all fields passed as params when attaching the behavior to the model, $Model::find() method doesn't get the inserted rows.

```
public $actsAs = array(
    'Translate' => array(
        'title' => 'title_Translation',
        'description' => 'description_Translation',
        'description_long' => 'description_long_Translation'
    )
);
```

Ex: if i pass to `$Model::save()` method only a value for `'title'`, the data is saved, even in the i18n table, but the `$Model::find()` doesn't get anything. I must pass data for all the fields.

Can I force it to retrieve those records ?

2) How can I get all the records in the admin side of the application (regardless of the language in which a record is saved) in order to list them so the user can alter it (edit data, save data in multiple languages)? Right now, I can only get the records that correspond to the current language (read from Configure or set explicitly)..

Thank you!

Comment: Same problem here. The query generated does an inner join with the translations table for each field translated, so if at least one of those is not present in the translation table then not even the original record is retrieved. If you need to add a new translated field to your existing model you're done.

Comment: I had the same problem and wrote some code to fix it... basically, after you add a new translatable field, you execute this code to go through and add the new translation records in the DB for all existing rows. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243785/add-a-new-translatable-field-to-an-existing-translatable-table-in-cakephp-2-2/13249219#13249219

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I might be a bit late, but anyway...

1) Cake uses an INNER JOIN when fetching a row and it's associated translations, so basically there's no easy way around this. You have to make sure you save every translatable field, every time - even if you just save it as blank. The only alternative would be to go hacking round the core to make it use a left join rather than an inner join - but don't do that.

2) The cookbook explains how to fetch all records here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html#retrieve-all-translation-records-for-a-field

Now, probably most of the time you want to get just one translation, so you don't want to modify the definition of your $actsAs['Translate'] array in your model. So what I did, was set up a method in AppModel.php which modifies the $actsAs['Translate'] array on the fly:

```
/*  
 * See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/translate.html#using-the-bindtranslation-method
 * This is for making it so we fetch all translations, as opposed to just that of the current locale.
 * Used for eg. editing (multiple translations) via the admin interface.
 */
public function bindAllTranslations(){
    $translatableFields = $this->actsAs['Translate'];

    $keyValueFields = array();
    foreach($translatableFields as $field){
        $keyValueFields[$field] = $field.'Translation';
    }

    $this->bindTranslation($keyValueFields,false);  // false means it will be changed for all future DB transactions in this page request - and won't be reset after the next transaction.
}
```

So, if it's an admin method (or any other situation you want all translations) you call that code before doing a find:

```
$this->MyModel->bindAllTranslations();
$this->MyModel->find('all');
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

I kind of solved it, I copied the TranslateBehavior to app/Model/Behavior (just to avoid problems on future upgrades and keep the original one just in case) then I changed the _addJoin(...) method of the behavior, just changed the join type from INNER to LEFT on line 255 (I use cake 2.2.3).

Now if a record exist it is always retrieved, even if translated fields are missing.

Don't see any drawbacks besides the need to check if the translation field is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if it will help in your case, but you can also use
array to set locale before you call *find()*

```
$this->YourModel->locale = array("ENG", "GER", "JAP");
```

This way you will always get all records even if they don't have all possible translations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot eleonzx, I'm having this problem since a decade, and with your simple answer I can now move forward ! So thanks again.

And maybe this code can help a lot of people :

in my AppController beforeFilter method I call _setLanguage

```
private function _setLanguage() {
    if($this->Session->read('Config.language')){
        $locale = $this->Session->read('Config.language');
        $this->{$this->modelClass}->setLocale($locale);
    }else{
        $this->{$this->modelClass}->Behaviors->disable('Translate');
    }
}
```

With the else condition I disable the Translate Behavior on the fly to get the original contents if there is no locale set in the session (I use basic links to switch between languages).